# Asp.net core Issue with JSON Serialize of Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Spatial.Point

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an address object using a Point

`address.Location = new Point(-0.332437, 51.374954);`

using JsonConvert.SerializeObject(address);
Will correctly output the JSON below

```
      "Location": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -0.332437,
          51.374954
        ]
```

However if I return this object as part of a WebAPI it will only return

```
 "location": {
   "type": "Point",   
   "coordinates": {}
 }
```

The coordinates are not returned, cant see why the result would be different. Thanks.

(DocumentDB client 1.22, aspnetcore 2.1)

Answer (score 0):

Appears to be working OK using code DocumentDB client